# NodeJS - fs.createReadStream() - how to cut off chunks at a certain point?

Tags: node.js, xml, fs, readfile

I have a large XML file (2GB) and I need to add a new line if a criterion is met. Example:

```
<chickens>
    <chicken>
        <name>sam</name>
        <female>false</female>
    </chicken>
    <chicken>
        <name>julia</name>
        <female>true</female>
    </chicken>
    // many many more chickens
</chickens>
```

to:

```
<chickens>
    <chicken>
        <name>sam</name>
        <female>false</female>
    </chicken>
    <chicken>
        <name>julia</name>
        <female>true</female>
        <canLayEggs>true</canLayEggs> // <- Add this line if female is true;
    </chicken>
    // many many more chickens
</chickens>
```

However, the issue that I'm facing is that sometimes the chunk gets cut off like `<female>true`
and then the next chunk starts with `</female>`

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const input = "input.xml";

const MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024; //50 MB
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);

let readStream = fs.createReadStream(input, "utf8", {
    highWaterMark: MAX_CHUNK_SIZE,
});
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.xml");

readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
    let data = chunk;
    if (data.includes("<category>f</category>")) {
        data = data.replace(
            /<female>true<\/female>/g,
            "<female>true</female><canLayEggs>true</canLayEggs>"
        );
    }
    writeStream.write(data, "utf-8");
});

readStream.on("end", () => {
    writeStream.end();
})
```

I have tried Google but I can't seem to find the right term, and many tutorials out there doesn't really cover this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are reading 50MB per chunk. so in the **on data** callback, you can call:

```
readStream.destroy();
```

also, you don't need to init the buffer with 50MB size, it is not used here and after the text replacement it is likely longer than 50MB.

It is good, that you close the writeStream when the readStream closes.